# Is this function surjective? And why?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated. I am really confused about all this, so please explain it in simple terms. I do understand what surjective means, however. Just not how to apply it to this example.

Comment: The domain has $2^8$ elements and the codomain has $2^9$, so it can't possibly be surjective.

Comment: That does make quite a lot of sense. Thanks for helping. I do feel silly for asking, but I would rather look silly than never know for sure, I guess.

Comment: @JakeJackson That's a good attitude to have! Asking questions is essential to improving your understanding

Comment: $$\forall y\in Y,\,\exists x\in X,\,f(x)=y\ ,$$
If for each y , there are  1 or more antecedent  , this application is surjective

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f$ is surjective, then for any element $b \in B^9$, there is some element $a \in B^8$ such that $f(a) = b$. Try to see if you can find something in $B^9$ that could not be expressed in this manner.

Answer (score 1):

If you take $\overline{1} =(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1) \in B^{9}$

Then there is not exist $b = (b_{1},\cdots,b_{8}) \in B^{8}$ such that $f(b) = \overline{1}$

Because, we would have $b_{1} = 1, b_{2} = 1, \cdots,b_{8} = 1$ and $b_{1} + \cdots + b_{8} = 8 \implies b_{9} = 0$